# WCF Serice Not working in REST

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to create custom wcf servic on sharepoint.
Unfoortuntly the service is working fine with WCF Test Client, But when i tried to access it through web/browser it is giving me empty screen or empty result in responce

Please some one assist me, Thank you so much in advance

### Interface

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", 
    UriTemplate = "/GetAllB/{value1}",        
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    string GetAllB(int val);
```

### Method

```
    public string GetAllB(int val)
    {
        return "Enterted Value is this" + val;
    }
```

### Web.config File

```
    <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior  name="Kuservice.Service1ServiceBehavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deploying the solution. -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deploying the solution to avoid disclosing exception information. -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>     
   </serviceBehaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
  <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>


</behaviors>
```

[image: Succcessfull Screen from WCF Test Client]

[image: Blank Result when tried with REST Client]

Comment: Your interface and implementation are correct for what you want to achive. Do you use the WebHttpBinding for the service endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider changing your config file to something like below,

```
    <configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfJsonRestService.Service1">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/service1" 
                  binding="webHttpBinding" 
                  contract="WcfJsonRestService.IService1"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```